# Does not work start script of iptables firewall in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, startup, iptables, init

Does not work start script of iptables firewall in Linux
I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          firewall
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"
START="/bin/bash"
PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
NAME="$0"
N="/etc/init.d/$NAME"

if [ ! -f /scripts/rc.firewall ]; then
echo "/scripts/rc.firewall does not exist"
exit 0
fi

case "$1" in
start|restart)
echo -n "Starting up iptables firewall..."
$START /scripts/rc.firewall
echo "done."
;;
stop)

$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT

$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -X

for TABLE in filter nat mangle
    do
        $IPTABLES -t $TABLE -F
        $IPTABLES -t $TABLE -X
        $IPTABLES -t $TABLE -Z
done

echo "done."
exit 0;
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $N {start|restart|stop}" >&2
exit 1
;;
esac

exit 0
```

This script starts other script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"

SSHport=$( set | grep "\(SSH_CONNECTION\)" | sed -e "s/^SSH_CONNECTION='//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9$

$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
$IPTABLES -t mangle -F

$IPTABLES -X
$IPTABLES -t nat -X
$IPTABLES -t mangle -X

/sbin/modprobe ip_tables
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack
/sbin/modprobe iptable_filter
/sbin/modprobe iptable_mangle
/sbin/modprobe iptable_nat
/sbin/modprobe ipt_LOG
/sbin/modprobe ipt_limit
/sbin/modprobe ipt_state
/sbin/modprobe ipt_owner
/sbin/modprobe ipt_REJECT
/sbin/modprobe ipt_MASQUERADE
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_irc
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_irc
/sbin/modprobe ip_gre
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_pptp

if [ -f /scripts/ssh_allow.txt ]; then
 for SSH_ALLOW in `grep -v ^# /scripts/ssh_allow.txt`; do
  $IPTABLES -A INPUT -s $SSH_ALLOW -p tcp -m tcp --dport $SSHport -j ACCEPT
  done
fi

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport $SSHport -j DROP

if [ -f /scripts/bad_input_ip.txt ]; then
 for BAD_INPUT_IP in `grep -v ^# /scripts/bad_input_ip.txt`; do
  $IPTABLES -A INPUT -s $BAD_INPUT_IP -j DROP
  done
fi

if [ -f /scripts/port_deny.txt ]; then
 for PORT_DENY in `grep -v ^# /scripts/port_deny.txt`; do
  $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT_DENY -j DROP
  done
fi
```

When i am trying to start:

`/etc/init.d/firewall start` everything is ok

But after adding of startup init script and reboot, i have only one rule:

```
iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2368 packets, 1433K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2   120 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
```

But i should have:

```
iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 226 packets, 110K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.110.22       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
   11   892 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.11.2         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.2          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.22         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.110.26       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.110.27       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.110.2        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.110.1        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.110.3        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.110.4        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
```

Where i have error ? Please help.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: i found a problem

Comment: this patter:

`SSHport=$( set | grep "\(SSH_CONNECTION\)" | sed -e "s/^SSH_CONNECTION='//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s/'//g" | grep "[0-9]*")`